# Is an async function returning a Task usable only by an async function?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to wade through the async functionality (C# .NET) and was curious whether an async function which returns a Task (i.e. promise) is always usable in an async function ONLY. Compiler and documentation indicate this of course, but I wanted to see if I am missing something which gets around this.

For example, the ReturnRandomIntegerAsync(i) returns a Task. **Note that the while loop which runs every 5 seconds is faster than the function which takes 7 seconds** :

```
        void MyFunction(){
           while(true)            
          {
            i++;
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Thread.Sleep(5000);                

            Task<int> j = ps.ReturnRandomIntegerAsync(i);// Call to an async 
            // method which has a sleep for 7 seconds (and awaits for sleep to be over))
            // **OUTPUT j**.

            sw.Stop();

            var timespan = sw.Elapsed;
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time : " + timespan.Seconds + "\n\n");// Time taken for this iteration. 
          }
        }
```

In this example, I cannot do an await on the ps.ReturnRandomIntegerAsync(i) unless I make the MyFunction() an async one. If I don't, then j is meaningless. If I do a .Result on the ps.ReturnRandomIntegerAsync(i), then it breaks async and the elapsed time (last line in while loop) shows 12 seconds (5 in the loop + 7 in the method).

If I want the value of j in every loop iteration ,the only solution I can think of in this scenario is to have j stored somewhere (array, collection etc.) by the async method and then retrieved later.

Would that be the correct approach ?

Comment: `Task` has been around for longer than `async` and `await`.

Comment: Question for you: here, I have a method Foo that returns `IEnumerable<int>`.  Am I *required* to `foreach` that sequence as soon as it is returned? If yes, why?  If no, what are some things I could do with an `IEnumerable<int>` other than `foreach`ing it? (In case it is not clear: `foreach` extracts values from sequences. `await` extracts values from tasks. Logically they are the almost same thing, so if you can answer the question about sequences, you probably already know the answer about tasks.)

Comment: @Eric, I see your point. And I think that is what I alluded to in the second to last para in my own question. To answer your question - No, I don't really need to foreach as soon as I receive the IEnumerable<int>. I can always add that to another collection (list, stack) and process it later. In my real-world example, the async is awaiting a 200 OK server response and updates a log ..... which I think the async method itself should be doing. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly store tasks and `await` them later.

`Task.WhenAll` is a common use case for this:

```
var task1 = SomethingAsync();
var task2 = SomethingElseAsync();

// Both operations are "in flight" at this point.

// Asynchronously wait for them both to complete.
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

Another example is for long-lived "main loop" kind of tasks. For example, a task that continually reads from a network stream. In this case, you want to eventually "join" with the task to be able to detect exceptions. My preferred method of doing this is to `await` the task in an `async Task` (or - very rarely - an `async void`) method, but you could also use `ContinueWith` to detect those exceptions.

Comment: That's still an example of using a `Task` returning method in an `async` method.  The question asks about calling such a method in a method that's not actually marked as `async`.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't *need* to use an `async` method to use a `Task`.  The `async` keyword is simply a language feature that makes working with asynchronous operations *more convenient*.  You can use the actual operations on `Task` itself (most notably `ContinueWith`) when writing a method and do it "the old way" if you want.

Alternatively some methods can be written entirely by composing other `Task` returning methods, and may not need to be `async` themselves.

Of course, it will indeed be quite common for methods you write that use `Task` instances to be `async`.  Situations in which it's unnecessary aren't super common, and writing things out by hand, without using the language feature, is almost always way more work and doesn't have a suitable benefit.

Comment: Ok, what I am hearing then is that instead of creating out an async method, I can do a Task.Run( <Method definition>) to avoid the await within MyMethod(). But if I want the result of the task in the example (j which is a random number) which takes longer than the loop, the only way would be that the Task that is run will handle the response and do whatever's necessary within Run() itself. I would have to do a Task.Wait if I want the answer within the while loop ..... which will basically halt the loop till Wait returns().

Comment: @user1554876 No, you should not be using `Task.Run` here at all.  If you want the loop to continue after the asynchronous operation has finished, you should `await` it.  You could use `ContinueWIth` to write the method without using the `async` keyword, but it would be a lot of work (to do correctly) for no real benefit.